# Spring AMQP- Receiving Message Object Instead of Content

Tags: spring-amqp

I'm using Spring AMQP to send message from one microservice to other one and get response.

I can send message and receive content with this code part:

```
public void sendAmqpCoreMessage(Message message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    List<MyCustomType> response = rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("jms.durable.queues", this.queue.getName(), message, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyCustomType>>() {
    });
    logger.info("Response: {}", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(response));
}
```

But instead of getting only message content, I need the whole Message object because I'm using some headers which stay in messageProperties of response which's type is Message.

How can I get Message object as response?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `convert...` methods with a `Message`, just use `sendAndReceive()`.